# Mongodb : Full text search for multiple phrases

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run a $text $search combining individual phrases in an OR statement,
such as “first phrase” OR “second phrase” OR "third phrase".
The following syntax won’t work: {$text: { $search: ““first phrase” “second phrase” "third phrase” } }

As mentioned in their documentation , $search operator given a string with a phrase searches only the phrase and ignores the rest .

For a workaround i am using regex to perform this action but its very slow .

Any idea how to achieve a “first phrase” OR “second phrase” OR "third phrase" with mongodb 3.4?

Comment: Do you use atlas?

Comment: no we are maintaining inhouse mongo cluster .

Comment: Can you explain with some data?

Comment: we have title field in one of our collection . we are searching in the title field where its contains one of phrases . like 
{ title : "Warehouse operative - Part time "}
we want to find document contain one of the phrase "warehouse operative" or "part time"

Comment: Regex would be slow as it may not use index. How did you use text search?

Comment: i cannot use text search because it does not support multiple phrase . right now i have done it using regex but quite slow .

Comment: You should consider at least testing this query out in Atlas Search because it will be much faster and easier.